# unable to create directory with name .dirname on nexus 5

Tags: android

I am unable to create directory with name .dirname in android kitket(nexus 5). so please suggest me what will I do to resolve this problem.when I call mkdirs() method it return false however I have set all permission on android manifest file.

following is my code:-

```
Map<String, File> externalLocations = ExternalStorage
                .getAllStorageLocations();
        File sdCard = externalLocations.get(ExternalStorage.SD_CARD);
        File externalSdCard = externalLocations
                .get(ExternalStorage.EXTERNAL_SD_CARD);
        Environment.getExternalStorageState();
       // long count = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (sdCard == null) {
            path = null;
        } else { 
            path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath().toString() +"/.DriverMaticsV/" + "12345" + "/Picture/";
        }
        if (externalSdCard != null) {
            if (storageLocInt == 0) {
                path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath().toString() +"/.DriverMaticsV/" + "12345" + "/Picture/";
            } else {
                path = externalSdCard.getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/.DriverMaticsV/" + "12345" + "/Picture/";
            }
        }
        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            boolean result = file.mkdirs();
            Utilities.showDLog("CamperaUtil", ""+result);
        }
```

Android Manifest permission:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application>.....</application>
```

Comment: no code = it never happened :)

Comment: please check my code.

Answer (score 0):

i think "dirname" is command name in linux, you cannot created directories with command name in linux, i will suggest that connect android device to windows machine and create directory from Windows commad prompt.

Comment: no, it is not. first thing is that "dirname" is only example name if you put any name for directory following with "." then it create problem on mkdirs() and second my device was attached with window system.